# Debug/Distribution discrepancy in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have searched and figured out how to change the name of my app (going through and changing the Product_Name) that shows up below the icon so now my app doesn't use the arbitrary name that I picked out when I started developing.

Now that I am using a distribution certificate - it goes back to the old one.  I changed the name of the .app file under the Products menu and it shows up just fine during the "debug" time of Xcode. As soon as I change the Overview slider to "distribution" it reverts back to the old .app name and for the life of me I can't change it.  What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for "Product Name" in the Project Settings screen.  I'll venture a guess that there are two different settings there, one for the "Debug" and another for the "Distribution" configurations.

Alternatively, you can also directly edit the "Bundle Display Name" in the (YourAppName)-Info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

There is "bundle display name" in the info.plist that can change the name under the icon on the device.